# How to run multiprocess Chroma.from_documents() in Langchain

Tags: python, embedding, langchain, multiprocessor, chromadb

Can we somehow pass an option to run multiple threads/processes when we call Chroma.from_documents() in Langchain?

I am trying to embed 980 documents (embedding model is mpnet on CUDA), and it take forever.
Specs:
Software: Ubuntu 20.4 (on Win11 WSL2 host), Langchain version:  0.0.253, pyTorch version: 2.0.1+cu118, Chroma Version: 0.4.2, CUDA 11.8
Processor: Intel i9-13900k at 5.4Ghz all 8 P-cores and 4.3Ghz all remaining 16 E-cores.
GPU: RTX 4090 GPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somehow it got resolved I think. I had to uninstall chroma/chroma-client and reinstall full chroma package. Also it helps incredibly if your   embeddings are device=cuda

Answer (score 0):

Chroma now supports [multiple threads](https://www.trychroma.com/blog/chroma_0.4.0), so this should be technically possible. Why not simply import threads and spawn multiple loaders?

Comment: how do we do this? i am using the langchain chroma wrapper.  Not using a chroma server...